# Existence of a det. poly-time algo for problem $f: X \to Y$.

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

$f : X \to Y$ is a deterministic polynomial-time algorithm for problem inputs $x \in X$ and problem outputs $f(x) = y \in Y \iff $there exists a polynomial $P_f \in \Bbb{Z}[x_1]$ such that $C\cdot P_f(|x|) = $ the running time on input $x, |x| = $ size of $x, C \in \Bbb{R}$.

**Conjecture**

Let $f: X \to Y$ specifiy a problem.

Then there is a det. poly-time algorithm for $f$ that uses *at most* $k$ words of memory each of size $n$ $\iff$ there exists $O(1)$ algorithms $\phi : X \to (\Bbb{Z_n})^k, \ \psi: (\Bbb{Z_n})^k \to Y$ and $k$ polynomials in $P_i \in \Bbb{Z_n}[z_1, \dots, z_k]$ such that $f = \psi \circ (P_1, \dots, P_k) \circ \phi$.

I think I can prove that too.  Has anyone looked into this yet?

$\phi, \psi$ are an encoder and decoder.  You have to represent sufficiently your inputs and outputs in your typical computer storage before you can solve the problem, right?  <strike>So it assumes all data needed to solve a problem has to be calculated when you run the algorithm.</strike>  No I think the precomputed data used to solve a problem is held in the constants of the polynomial or equivalently in the code specifying the algorithm.

This might have important implications such as the set of all poly-time algorithms is finite for finite data memory (or something...) and a natural ring structure on the set of algorithms.

Comment: Actually that's not true.  The exponents in the polynomials need to depend on the inputs. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are asking the question does LOGSPACE = P, which remains an open question similar to the P vs NP problem.

It is known that the use of constant space $\subset$ LOGSPACE $\subset$ PSPACE, where PSPACE uses polynomial space, and it known that LOGSPACE is contained within P.  It is generally believed that LOGSPACE $\subset$ P $\subset$ NP $\subset$ PSPACE, but only the first and last containments are known to be strict.